# Calling another view page through ajax in codeigniter view page

Tags: codeigniter

I have a view page, from that page I want to call another view page through ajax. This is the code i'm using, but I'm not getting the response.
This is my code

```
var dataString = 'product_name='+product_name+'&qty='+qty+'&cost='+price;

$.ajax({
url:'myCart.php',
type:"get",
data: dataString,
success:function(data)
{
 alert(data);

}
 });
```

This is my myCart.php. In this I have get all the values passed from that page though url.

```
<?php
session_start();

if (!isset($_SESSION['SHOPPING_CART'])){ 
  $_SESSION['SHOPPING_CART'] = array(); 
}

$session = $_SESSION['SHOPPING_CART'];
function inMultiArray($name,$session) {
if (array_key_exists($name,$session) or in_array($name,$session)) {
         return true;
    } else {
        $return = false;
        foreach (array_values($session) as $value) {
            if (is_array($value) and !$return) {
                $return = inMultiArray($name,$value);
            }
        }
        return $return;
   }
  }
  $name = 'Test' ;
  $result = inMultiArray($name,$session);
  if($result){
    echo 'Yes';
   } 
   // else, add the item to the array
  else{
  $ITEM = array(
  //Item name  
   'product_name' => $_GET['product_name'], 
  //Item Price
    'cost' => $_GET['cost'], 
   //Qty wanted of item
  'qty' => $_GET['qty']  
  );

  //Add this item to the shopping cart
 $_SESSION['SHOPPING_CART'][] =  $ITEM;
 $total=0;
 foreach ($_SESSION['SHOPPING_CART'] as $itemNumber => $items) {
 $total = $total + $items['cost'];
 // print $items['cost']; 
 // print $items['qty'];    
 }
 echo $total; 
 }

 ?>
```

Comment: check your console to find out the error

Comment: Am using notepad++ how can I find out error!

Comment: when your run your file on browser using firebug you can check the errors.

Comment: Is this right way to call php file through ajax in view page?

Comment: what is `enter code herevar dataString`? this is wrong

Comment: I have edited my code and included the myCart.php file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I now clearly understood your question, it is wrong to call a view. Instead call your controller which will call the model to perform some operation and return the result you want

Comment: This is the code I tried, sorry while adding the code made a mistake. This is not working.

Comment: @hudson on browser press `f12` key and check console for error and tell me what error do you see there?

Comment: both the php files are within View folder of my project.

Comment: its ok if php files are on same folder. see for errors then we can tell you the exact solution for this

Comment: In alert I'm getting the HTML code of the same page.

Comment: Edit your question and add your myCart.php file code there

Comment: @RakeshShetty you can not call a view directly like that in CI. calls are made to controller for such purpose.